# Формат записи даты

Tags: общие-вопросы, даты

В предложении написано: *Приглашаем посетить наш стенд с 21.06 - 23.06 2016.*

Ясно, что неправильно... Либо "с... по" Либо "с" убрать, но как тогда быть с годом? Запуталась... Как правильно?

Answer (score 2):

Это два вопроса, одно с другим не связано.

Конечно, такая форма "с XXX-YYY" неправильна, несмотря на частое употребление.
Как править, Вы сами написали.

А вот в отношении года - тут особых проблем нет. Он относится к обеим датам.
Вы же в устной речи можете сказать что-то типа "С первого по девятое мая шестнадцатого года"?! Или "С тридцатого июня по пятое июля такого-то года"?!
Надо того оформить так, чтобы зрительно не путалось.

Варианты:
***с 21.06 по 23.06 2016 г.***
***21.06 - 23.06 2016-го г.***
***с 21-го по 23 июня 2016 г.***
- и еще масса других.

Еще одно замечание. Если "стенд" - это именно стенд, то "посетить стенд" - плохо. "Посетить" можно место, где этот стенд находится.

Сравните: посетить Третьяковку, посетить выставку. *Посетить экспозицию* -  уже вызывает вопросы. Ну а *посетить картину "Три Богатыря"* - это только в переносном смысле. Так и стенд. 
Не совсем понимаю контекст, поэтому не рискую предлагать правку, но "посетить стенд" надо бы на что-то сменить - смотрите сами, на что.

Comment: Спасибо. Только буквенное наращение.у дат, по-моему, не ставится... Только если год пишется отдельно.

Comment: Так у нас везде **год** и пишется **отдельно**. А вообще это правило довольно путанное и больше относится к сфере типографии, чем правописания. Мо;ет, корректоры меня поправят...

Comment: Из этих трёх вариантов для интервала внутри одного месяца наиболее приятен **с 21-го по 23 июня 2016 г.** Также можно использовать международный стандарт [ISO 8601](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), но на свой страх и риск: **с 2016-06-21 по 2016-06-23**

Comment: Сокращение **г.** или слово **года** используется только при записи месяца буквами: **5 июня 2003 г.**, но не при записи арабскими цифрами: **05.06.2003**, см. [ГОСТ Р 6.30-2003](https://img.artlebedev.ru/kovodstvo/sections/102/GOST_R_6.30-2003.pdf), п. 3.11

Comment: @Smylic *но не при записи арабскими цифрами: 05.06.2003*  - спасибо, но зачем ві мне об этом сообщаете? Я не использую и не предлагаю использовать что-то подпадающее под это "но не арабскими".

Comment: @behemothus Перефразирую: при записи даты только арабскими цифрами и разделяющими их точками **г.** или **года** не пишется

Comment: @Smylic Повторю вопрос. Зачем Вы мне об этом сообщаете с такой настойчивостью? Я с Вами не спорю.

Answer (score 0):

Приглашаем посетить наш стенд 21.06 — 23.06 с.г.

Приглашаем посетить наш стенд 21.VI — 23.VI 2016 г.

Comment: Мне кажется, сокращение _"сего года"_ не считается официальным... Где-то такую информацию встречала.

Comment: Это текст Приглашения, а не Титул, в котором уже проставлены дата, место, название мероприятия. Текст Приглашения вторичен, он — «внутри», и указание года события повторно — не признак хорошего тона: не великое событие выставка в выходные дни. Да и Приглашение, отправленное в середине текущего года может ли говорить о мероприятии года другого.

Comment: Ну, это реклама, которая содержит в себе приглашение... И там так и написали "с..." и дальше через тире... Но я встречала рекламу мероприятий уже следующего года в текущих изданиях. Но в любом случае спасибо. В приглашении такая форма записи действительно смотрелась бы оригинально.

Comment: @Alenka *Мне кажется, сокращение "сего года" не считается официальным...* - оно сильно устарело вместе со всей формой "сего года/месяца/числа".